# Min function for functions f1, f2,

Tags: function-construction, algebraic-manipulation

There are several "min" functions in Mathematica. In the "Numerical" category, there is a "Min" function that works on a numerical list. Then there's MinValue for finding the minimum of a whole function (FindMinimum) and other variations of this. What I'm looking for is a "min" function that takes several functions (f1, f2, ...) and returns the output of function (fn) across the domain that it (fn) has the lowest values. Say,

```
Min(-x^2, -(x + 1)^2)

=> -x^2         when x < -1/2,
   -(x + 1)^2   when x >= -1/2
```

Is there such a function in Mathematica? If not, how do I define one? It has to seemlessly work with all the other built-in functions in Mathematica so I don't always have to be worrying about the gaps.

At least Wolfram|Alpha can do the "min" function.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Doesn't `Min` already do what you're looking for? `Plot[Min[-x^2, -(x + 1)^2], {x, -1, 0}]`.  `Min` works on anyting, not just numbers.  E.g. `Min[{2,3,x}]` --> `Min[2,x]` as it's not know whether `x` is smaller than `2`.

Comment: Read the documentation, tutorials here, etc. Then write your own, this is trivial.

Comment: @Szabolcs Could possibly the OP want as actual output something like a `Piecewise` expression?  Not for the sake of evaluation but for information?

Comment: I really don't need to plot it, so I've never tried to. Yeah, it works. But what I'm really looking for is a function that symbolically can work with other more core functions. Say, Refine[Assuming[a < 5, Min[a, 7]]] will have output of "a".

Comment: Please put that, and any other examples you have, in the question.

Comment: @Badadeeboop You used `Refine` and `Assuming` in the wrong order.  `Assuming` is always outside.

Comment: @MrW: Yup that is what I intend to do. I wanted a computer algebra system to automatically breakdown all the domains and define "Piecewise" functions as solutions. That way I won't have to track everything down. Thanks for reminding me the name of those "glued together" functions.

Comment: `Min[]` works with `PiecewiseExpand[]` too.

Comment: @Guesswho Crikey!  I never realized that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just maybe this is related to what you want?

```
min[a_, b_] := Piecewise[{{a, #}, {b, ! #}}] & @ Reduce[a < b]

min[x__] := Fold[min, {x}] // PiecewiseExpand

min[-x^2, -(x + 1)^2]
```

> ```
> Piecewise[{{-x^2, x < -1/2}, {-(1 + x)^2, x >= -1/2}}, 0]
> ```

---

[J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/) just pointed out in a comment that [`Min`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Min.html) already works this way when using [`PiecewiseExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html):

```
Min[-x^2, -(x + 1)^2] // PiecewiseExpand
```

> ```
> Piecewise[{{-x^2, x <= -1/2}}, -(1 + x)^2]
> ```

I guess that makes my code pretty useless but so be it.

Comment: Awesome! Looks easy enough. This will work with "Refine[Assuming[a < 5, Min[a, 7]]]"?? Sorry, will have to look into other things in your solution I haven't encountered before and it's already late where I'm at.

Comment: But it does look it only works on discrete lists, still.

Comment: @Badadeeboop `Assuming[a < 5, Refine @ min[a, 7]]` does return `a`.   I am not sure what you mean by "it only works on discrete lists" however.

Comment: I guess we don't have to define it with "Fold".